# Issues with number format in Excel (European settings)

Tags: excel, csv

I am having issues when opening a .csv file in Excel 365. The decimal point is appearing at strange positions in the numbers as shown below:
15.99 should 1.599 and 54.751 should be 5.4751...
I have tried many ways to change the formatting but it does not work.

[image]

Comment: The numbers you mention in  your description do not appear in your example screenshot making an intelligent response difficult. Data should be posted as text. In general, CSV files should be **import**ed and not **open**ed. **Import**ing provides an opportunity to properly set things like decimals, thousands separators, date format, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the file open settings:
[image]

You have options to:

1. Import values as text then process data as you need.
2. Customize the decimal separator.